# How To turn a string with "pipe-separated" values into individual rows in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, query, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, string-manipulation

I have a table with below structure :

```
create table student_info
(
  item_number    number,
  st_firstname   varchar2(50),
  st_lastname    varchar2(50),
  st_score       varchar2(50)
)
```

Here is a sample data of the table :

```
item_number  |  st_firstname   |         st_lastname      |  st_score
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1         Ali|Reza|Pantea    Hashemi|Nosrati|Yaghobi    10|20|20
     
     2          Maryam|Ahmad         Moghise|Majlesi          20|20
```

I need to have the below output:

```
item_number  |  st_firstname   |         st_lastname      |  st_score
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1             Ali                    Hashemi               10
     1             Reza                   Nosrati               20
     1             Pantea                 Yaghobi               20
     
     2             Maryam                 Moghise               20
     2             Ahmad                  Majlesi               20
```

I've found that with below query, I can do what I want with one of the columns (Which is `st_firstname`):

```
select distinct t.item_number,
                trim(regexp_substr(t.st_firstname, '[^|]+', 1, level)) str
  from student_info t
connect by instr(st_firstname, '|', 1, level - 1) > 0
 order by t.item_number
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add other columns(st_lastname , st_lastname) to above query. I was wondering if you could help me here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add in additional columns, e.g.:

```
WITH student_info AS (SELECT 1 item_number, 'Ali|Reza|Pantea' st_firstname, 'Hashemi|Nosrati|Yaghobi' st_lastname, '10|20|20' st_score FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 2 item_number, 'Maryam|Ahmad' st_firstname, 'Moghise|Majlesi' st_lastname, '20|20' st_score FROM dual)
SELECT t.item_number,
       LEVEL lvl,
       TRIM(regexp_substr(t.st_firstname, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL)) first_name,
       TRIM(regexp_substr(t.st_lastname, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL)) last_name,
       TRIM(regexp_substr(t.st_score, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL)) score
FROM   student_info t
CONNECT BY PRIOR item_number = item_number
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
           AND instr(st_firstname, '|', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
ORDER  BY t.item_number, LEVEL;


ITEM_NUMBER        LVL FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME               SCORE
----------- ---------- --------------- ----------------------- --------
          1          1 Ali             Hashemi                 10
          1          2 Reza            Nosrati                 20
          1          3 Pantea          Yaghobi                 20
          2          1 Maryam          Moghise                 20
          2          2 Ahmad           Majlesi                 20
```

N.B. I have updated the `connect by` clause to restrict it to looping over each row, rather than it trying to hierarchically connect all the rows together (that way madness lies! And also poor performance, if your dataset has many rows in it). Note that because of that, you no longer need the `distinct`, as the "duplicate" rows are no longer produced.

Comment: Thanks, It works well for me. Just a few questions, Could you explain this part: 
"PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL" ? 
What does this part do and what will happen if I remove this part?

Comment: There are some good explanations in this [Oracle Forum post](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/reg-sys-guid-6983) - especially one of BluShadow's comments, (search for "break it down to basics" on the page)